# Applying a configuration file using Kubectl -f filename.yml but getting this error

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have a deployment yaml file created. I am trying to apply this configuration using `kubectl apply -f filename.yml`, but I am getting this error:  `The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?`

How can I make sure that I connect to `localhost:8080`? or remove any restrictions in doing so?

Comment: Are you actually running Kubernetes, directly on the host?  That’s an unusual configuration; you’re probably missing some required setup in your `$HOME/.kube/config` file which depends on what flavor of Kubernetes exactly you’re using.

Comment: How are you running your kubernetes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**kubectl is a command-line tool tool that allows you to run commands against Kubernetes clusters**

By default **kubectl looks for a file named config in the $HOME/.kube directory** to connect with cluster. ensure you have a file named config with correct values in this path.

```
$ pwd
/home/ubuntu/.kube

$ ll
total 88
drwxrwxrwx 4 ubuntu ubuntu  4096 Jan 16 10:31 ./
drwxr-xr-x 7 ubuntu ubuntu  4096 Jan 16 10:30 ../
drwxr-x--- 3 ubuntu ubuntu  4096 Jan 13 13:00 cache/
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu  5455 Jan 13 15:17 config*
```

You can specify other kubeconfig files by setting the KUBECONFIG environment variable or by setting the --kubeconfig flag.

**Note: If you use `--kubeconfig` to pass config file it takes precedence over the KUBECONFIG environment variable**.

Example : Setting KUBECONFIG env varaible.

```
$ KUBECONFIG=$HOME/.kube/cluster-1

$ kubectl cluster-info
Kubernetes master is running at https://xx.xx.xx.101:6443
KubeDNS is running at https://xx.xx.xx.101:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy

To further debug and diagnose cluster problems, use 'kubectl cluster-info dump'.
```

Example : Using --kubeconfig to pass config file to override default KUBECONFIG

```
$ kubectl cluster-info --kubeconfig=/home/ubuntu/.kube/cluster-2
Kubernetes master is running at https://xx.xx.xx.102:6443
KubeDNS is running at https://xx.xx.xx.102:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy

To further debug and diagnose cluster problems, use 'kubectl cluster-info dump'.
```

**To reproduce your error I simply set KUBECONFIG to empty to show that you are missing this setting when running kubectl commands**

```
$ KUBECONFIG=""

$ kubectl get pods
The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your `kubectl` CLI is not configured properly.

By default, kubectl looks for a file named config in the `$HOME/.kube` directory. You can specify other kubeconfig files by setting the `KUBECONFIG` environment variable or by setting the `--kubeconfig` flag.